# NgIF with 3 or clauses and null objects

Tags: angular

it looks like I do not know how to create an NgIf with 3 Or clauses together, but I can not find what is wrong or any example to copy from:

```
*ngIf="owner === photo.calbum.community.user.id || owner === photo.album.user.id || isAdmin == true"
```

Then I have a JSON object that in some records but sometimes it has a photo from an Album (or it is null), or sometimes it has a common album that belong to a community (or it is null because the photo belong to an Album).

In both cases they all belong to a user, but through different objects. But one of them will be null always and I need to check the whole JSON file.

Thanks.

Comment: That `or` statement is fine, what issue are you having with it?

Comment: in general its a better practice to create a get param, lets say "shouldDisplay" which will evaluate this boolean statement.

Comment: can you show a minimal example (stackblitz, plunkr, ...) of not working code??

Comment: why don't add a boolean variable  in component and try to assign your condition value to it in constructor. add that variable in `*ngIf` here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use (?) operator if any of the object or it 's property `null`

```
*ngIf="owner === photo?.calbum?.community?.user?.id || owner === photo?.album?.user?.id || isAdmin == true"
```

[The safe navigation operator ( ?. ) and null property paths](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

Another option is to create a property or function and you can check this value only but you need to handle check the value is null.

```
get state() : boolean{
  if (this.isAdmin ) {
    return true
  } else if (this.photo && this.photo.calbum) {
    return this.owner === this.photo.calbum.community.user.id
  } else if (this.photo && this.photo.album) {
    return this.owner === this.photo.album.user.id
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

template

```
 <div *ngIf="state">/<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. because I think your condition seems like good with boolean in html then why don't try it with component

```
    isTrue:boolean;

    constructor(){
    if((this.photo != null && (this.owner === this.photo.calbum.community.user.id || this.owner === this.photo.album.user.id)) || this.isAdmin == true){
         this.isTrue=true;
    }else {
         this.isTrue=false;
    }
 }
```

and in html add this `*ngIf=isTrue;` or you can do in a method instead of constructor as per your requirement and call it from `html`

Comment: if photo object or it 's property is null or undefined you will get an error can't read calbum of nulll or undefined depend of the value of the object

Comment: you need to use this.owner , this.photo , this.isAdmin , handle this at the template with ? operater seem easer just look to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use a getter

in your component

```
get my(){
 return //all your conditions
}

*ngIf="my"
```